# ArgumentError: invalid number of elements (3 for 1..2) rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production

I am facing a weird issue. I work on rails with sharetribe and changed some value in a file. When I do "git push heroku master", I know get the error, which I didn't have just before :

```
Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     ArgumentError: invalid number of elements (3 for 1..2)
remote:  !     /tmp/build_70dda8da62b1a30d22f426adaa24f35b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:76:in `[]'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_70dda8da62b1a30d22f426adaa24f35b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:76:in `query_hash'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_70dda8da62b1a30d22f426adaa24f35b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:85:in `raw_config'
```

Even if I change back the file I updated, I keep having the error... I don't get it in local. Do you have any idea how I can handle that ?

I'm using rails 2.4.4 . Thanks a lot

Comment: Rails 2.4! Have you configured database on heroku correctly?

Comment: I did  heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite and then set heroku config:set DATABASE_URL with the ssl files. The only error I get when I launch "heroku run bundle exec rake db:structure:load" is the one above